# How to add the values in a dictionary with a condition?

Tags: python, dictionary

Here I have a dictionary of multiples stocks, where I have a token number as the main key.

```py
   {14350850: {'name': 'ACC19DEC1360CE', 'Strike': 1360, 'LTP': 87.85}, 
    14351106: {'name': 'ACC19DEC1360PE', 'Strike': 1360, 'LTP': 1.2}, 
    14351362: {'name': 'ACC19DEC1380CE', 'Strike': 1380, 'LTP': 74.0}, 
    14351618: {'name': 'ACC19DEC1380PE', 'Strike': 1380, 'LTP': 0.95}, 
    14351874: {'name': 'ACC19DEC1400CE', 'Strike': 1400, 'LTP': 60.55}, 
    14352130: {'name': 'ACC19DEC1400PE', 'Strike': 1400, 'LTP': 1.7}, 
    22655746: {'name': 'TATACHEM19DEC450CE', 'Strike': 450, 'LTP': 0.0}, 
    22656002: {'name': 'TATACHEM19DEC450PE', 'Strike': 450, 'LTP': 0.0}, 
    22656258: {'name': 'TATACHEM19DEC460CE', 'Strike': 460, 'LTP': 0.0}, 
    22656514: {'name': 'TATACHEM19DEC460PE', 'Strike': 460, 'LTP': 0.0}, 
    22656770: {'name': 'TATACHEM19DEC470CE', 'Strike': 470, 'LTP': 0.0}, 
    22657026: {'name': 'TATACHEM19DEC470PE', 'Strike': 470, 'LTP': 0.0}, 
    22657282: {'name': 'TATACHEM19DEC480CE', 'Strike': 480, 'LTP': 0.0}, 
    22657538: {'name': 'TATACHEM19DEC480PE', 'Strike': 480, 'LTP': 0.0}, 
    22657794: {'name': 'TATACHEM19DEC490CE', 'Strike': 490, 'LTP': 0.0}, 
    22658050: {'name': 'TATACHEM19DEC490PE', 'Strike': 490, 'LTP': 0.0}, 
    22658306: {'name': 'TATACHEM19DEC500CE', 'Strike': 500, 'LTP': 0.0}, 
    22658562: {'name': 'TATACHEM19DEC500PE', 'Strike': 500, 'LTP': 0.0}, 
    22658818: {'name': 'TATACHEM19DEC510CE', 'Strike': 510, 'LTP': 0.0}, 
    22659074: {'name': 'TATACHEM19DEC510PE', 'Strike': 510, 'LTP': 0.0}, 
    22659330: {'name': 'TATACHEM19DEC520CE', 'Strike': 520, 'LTP': 0.0}, 
    22659586: {'name': 'TATACHEM19DEC520PE', 'Strike': 520, 'LTP': 0.0}, 
    22659842: {'name': 'TATACHEM19DEC530CE', 'Strike': 530, 'LTP': 0.0}, 
    22660098: {'name': 'TATACHEM19DEC530PE', 'Strike': 530, 'LTP': 0.0}, 
    22660354: {'name': 'TATACHEM19DEC540CE', 'Strike': 540, 'LTP': 0.0}, 
    22660610: {'name': 'TATACHEM19DEC540PE', 'Strike': 540, 'LTP': 0.0}, 
    22660866: {'name': 'TATACHEM19DEC550CE', 'Strike': 550, 'LTP': 0.0}, 
    22680578: {'name': 'TATACHEM19DEC550PE', 'Strike': 550, 'LTP': 0.0}, 
    22680834: {'name': 0.0}, 
    18314498: {'name': 'DLF19DEC135PE', 'Strike': 135, 'LTP': 4.0}, 
    18314754: {'name': 'DLF19DEC135CE', 'Strike': 135, 'LTP': 5}, 
    18315010: {'name': 'DLF19DEC140PE', 'Strike': 140, 'LTP': 1.2}, 
    18315266: {'name': 'DLF19DEC140CE', 'Strike': 140, 'LTP': 2.0}}
```

Let me explain what each term in dictionary means for one line item `18315266: {'name': 'DLF19DEC140CE', 'Strike': 140, 'LTP': 2.0}}`

`18315266` - Token number name - DLF (stock name and CE (Call option)) STrike - 140 ( I want to add LTP of both 140 ce and 140 pe)
LTP - Last traded price

Here I have a dictionary of multiples stocks, where I have token number as the main key. Inside it we have "name", "Strike" and "LTP" Stocks are filtered by "name" I want to add the LTP of all SAME STRIKE(ex- 135ce and 135 pe) of SAME STOCK (ex-DLF) and then find the minimum combined LTP. For ex- DLFminimumprice( variable) shall be minimum of (combined ltp of 135 Strikeprice and 140 strike price) min ( 9 or 3.2). So it should give me 3.2.

So in a nutshell, I want to add ltp in pairs (where the strike is the same, one for call and second for put), then compare which ltp pair is the minimum of them). I want this minimum value I want this for each and every stock given in the dictionary and I will have more than 200 stocks to do this activity.

Comment: I am still a beginner in python but still I tried very hard to solve this. I have been stuck on it for the lasy 5-6 days. I know how to extract keys and values through loop but not sure how to extract it having multiple conditions.

Comment: `if condition1 and condition2:`

Comment: Since I have around 200 stocks on which I have to perform this, do I have to 2 loops along with dictionary filter . One for stocks and second for strike price ?strikes = [1360,1380,1400,135,140]
stocks = ["DLF","ACC","TATACHEM"]

for b in dic.values():
    
    for w in b.values():
        if "ACC" in w:
            print("Yes")             Lets say if we get acc with 1300 ce strike, through loop, how can I store it and make it add to 1300 pe ? similarly I have to find minimum values of all the strike prices LTP ?

Comment: You can probably do it in a single loop by creating a new dictionary that's keyed by the values you want to group on.

Comment: _I have been stuck on it for the lasy 5-6 days._ What have you come up with in that time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `pandas` and `groupby` it could be easier

First I convert it to `DataFrame` and uses `name` to create column `Stock`.

Next I group by `Stock` and `Strike` and get `sum()`

When I have DataFrame with sums then I group by `Stock` and get `min()`

```
data = {14350850: {'name': 'ACC19DEC1360CE', 'Strike': 1360, 'LTP': 87.85}, 
    14351106: {'name': 'ACC19DEC1360PE', 'Strike': 1360, 'LTP': 1.2}, 
    14351362: {'name': 'ACC19DEC1380CE', 'Strike': 1380, 'LTP': 74.0}, 
    14351618: {'name': 'ACC19DEC1380PE', 'Strike': 1380, 'LTP': 0.95}, 
    14351874: {'name': 'ACC19DEC1400CE', 'Strike': 1400, 'LTP': 60.55}, 
    14352130: {'name': 'ACC19DEC1400PE', 'Strike': 1400, 'LTP': 1.7}, 
    22655746: {'name': 'TATACHEM19DEC450CE', 'Strike': 450, 'LTP': 0.0}, 
    22656002: {'name': 'TATACHEM19DEC450PE', 'Strike': 450, 'LTP': 0.0}, 
    22656258: {'name': 'TATACHEM19DEC460CE', 'Strike': 460, 'LTP': 0.0}, 
    22656514: {'name': 'TATACHEM19DEC460PE', 'Strike': 460, 'LTP': 0.0}, 
    22656770: {'name': 'TATACHEM19DEC470CE', 'Strike': 470, 'LTP': 0.0}, 
    22657026: {'name': 'TATACHEM19DEC470PE', 'Strike': 470, 'LTP': 0.0}, 
    22657282: {'name': 'TATACHEM19DEC480CE', 'Strike': 480, 'LTP': 0.0}, 
    22657538: {'name': 'TATACHEM19DEC480PE', 'Strike': 480, 'LTP': 0.0}, 
    22657794: {'name': 'TATACHEM19DEC490CE', 'Strike': 490, 'LTP': 0.0}, 
    22658050: {'name': 'TATACHEM19DEC490PE', 'Strike': 490, 'LTP': 0.0}, 
    22658306: {'name': 'TATACHEM19DEC500CE', 'Strike': 500, 'LTP': 0.0}, 
    22658562: {'name': 'TATACHEM19DEC500PE', 'Strike': 500, 'LTP': 0.0}, 
    22658818: {'name': 'TATACHEM19DEC510CE', 'Strike': 510, 'LTP': 0.0}, 
    22659074: {'name': 'TATACHEM19DEC510PE', 'Strike': 510, 'LTP': 0.0}, 
    22659330: {'name': 'TATACHEM19DEC520CE', 'Strike': 520, 'LTP': 0.0}, 
    22659586: {'name': 'TATACHEM19DEC520PE', 'Strike': 520, 'LTP': 0.0}, 
    22659842: {'name': 'TATACHEM19DEC530CE', 'Strike': 530, 'LTP': 0.0}, 
    22660098: {'name': 'TATACHEM19DEC530PE', 'Strike': 530, 'LTP': 0.0}, 
    22660354: {'name': 'TATACHEM19DEC540CE', 'Strike': 540, 'LTP': 0.0}, 
    22660610: {'name': 'TATACHEM19DEC540PE', 'Strike': 540, 'LTP': 0.0}, 
    22660866: {'name': 'TATACHEM19DEC550CE', 'Strike': 550, 'LTP': 0.0}, 
    22680578: {'name': 'TATACHEM19DEC550PE', 'Strike': 550, 'LTP': 0.0}, 
    22680834: {'name': 0.0}, 
    18314498: {'name': 'DLF19DEC135PE', 'Strike': 135, 'LTP': 4.0}, 
    18314754: {'name': 'DLF19DEC135CE', 'Strike': 135, 'LTP': 5}, 
    18315010: {'name': 'DLF19DEC140PE', 'Strike': 140, 'LTP': 1.2}, 
    18315266: {'name': 'DLF19DEC140CE', 'Strike': 140, 'LTP': 2.0}}

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data).T
df['Stock'] = df['name'].str.extract('(\D+)')
print(df)

sums = df[['LTP','Stock', 'Strike']].groupby(['Stock', 'Strike']).sum().reset_index()
print(sums)

results = sums[['LTP','Stock']].groupby('Stock').min().reset_index()
print(results)
```

Result `df`:

```
            LTP Strike                name     Stock
14350850  87.85   1360      ACC19DEC1360CE       ACC
14351106    1.2   1360      ACC19DEC1360PE       ACC
14351362     74   1380      ACC19DEC1380CE       ACC
14351618   0.95   1380      ACC19DEC1380PE       ACC
14351874  60.55   1400      ACC19DEC1400CE       ACC
14352130    1.7   1400      ACC19DEC1400PE       ACC
22655746      0    450  TATACHEM19DEC450CE  TATACHEM
22656002      0    450  TATACHEM19DEC450PE  TATACHEM
22656258      0    460  TATACHEM19DEC460CE  TATACHEM
22656514      0    460  TATACHEM19DEC460PE  TATACHEM
22656770      0    470  TATACHEM19DEC470CE  TATACHEM
22657026      0    470  TATACHEM19DEC470PE  TATACHEM
22657282      0    480  TATACHEM19DEC480CE  TATACHEM
22657538      0    480  TATACHEM19DEC480PE  TATACHEM
22657794      0    490  TATACHEM19DEC490CE  TATACHEM
22658050      0    490  TATACHEM19DEC490PE  TATACHEM
22658306      0    500  TATACHEM19DEC500CE  TATACHEM
22658562      0    500  TATACHEM19DEC500PE  TATACHEM
22658818      0    510  TATACHEM19DEC510CE  TATACHEM
22659074      0    510  TATACHEM19DEC510PE  TATACHEM
22659330      0    520  TATACHEM19DEC520CE  TATACHEM
22659586      0    520  TATACHEM19DEC520PE  TATACHEM
22659842      0    530  TATACHEM19DEC530CE  TATACHEM
22660098      0    530  TATACHEM19DEC530PE  TATACHEM
22660354      0    540  TATACHEM19DEC540CE  TATACHEM
22660610      0    540  TATACHEM19DEC540PE  TATACHEM
22660866      0    550  TATACHEM19DEC550CE  TATACHEM
22680578      0    550  TATACHEM19DEC550PE  TATACHEM
22680834    NaN    NaN                   0       NaN
18314498      4    135       DLF19DEC135PE       DLF
18314754      5    135       DLF19DEC135CE       DLF
18315010    1.2    140       DLF19DEC140PE       DLF
18315266      2    140       DLF19DEC140CE       DLF
```

Result `sums`:

```
       Stock  Strike    LTP
0        ACC    1360  89.05
1        ACC    1380  74.95
2        ACC    1400  62.25
3        DLF     135   9.00
4        DLF     140   3.20
5   TATACHEM     450   0.00
6   TATACHEM     460   0.00
7   TATACHEM     470   0.00
8   TATACHEM     480   0.00
9   TATACHEM     490   0.00
10  TATACHEM     500   0.00
11  TATACHEM     510   0.00
12  TATACHEM     520   0.00
13  TATACHEM     530   0.00
14  TATACHEM     540   0.00
15  TATACHEM     550   0.00
```

Result `results`:

```
      Stock    LTP
0       ACC  62.25
1       DLF   3.20
2  TATACHEM   0.00
```

Comment: Thanks .it works but I have to do this process real time, i.e. calculate the minimum price on real time data on 200 stocks. Do u think this process of converting the dict to df will be fast enough ?

Comment: it uses `numpy` and code in C/C++ so it should be faster then Python code. But for small data it is hard to see it.